# haskell fromInteger with multiple data constructors

Tags: haskell, constructor, return

I am looking for a solution that is quite generic I think. My goal is to find a clean way to do operations on Points (coordinates), either in 2D or 3D. my data Point is an instance of Num that gives functions to do basics maths operations.

```
data Point = Point2D Float Float
       | Point3D Float Float Float deriving Show

add :: Point -> Point -> Point
add (Point2D xa ya) (Point2D xb yb) = Point2D (xa+xb) (ya+yb)
add (Point3D xa ya za) (Point3D xb yb zb) = Point3D (xa+xb) (ya+yb) (za+zb)

divT (Point2D x y) v = Point2D (x / v) (y / v)
divT (Point3D x y z) v = Point3D (x / v) (y / v) (z / v)

fromIntegerP :: Integer -> Point
fromIntegerP v = Point2D (fromIntegral v) 0
--fromIntegerP v = Point3D (fromIntegral v) 0 0

instance Num Point where
    (+) = add
    fromInteger = fromIntegerP

p2D1 = Point2D 1.0 2.0
p2D2 = Point2D 4.0 5.0
p3D1 = Point3D 1.0 2.0 3.0
p3D2 = Point3D 6.0 6.0 6.0

main = do
    putStrLn . show $ sum [p2D1,p2D2]
    putStrLn . show $ sum [p3D1,p3D2]
```

This code outputs :

```
Point2D 5.0 7.0
*** Exception: pointStackoverflow.hs:(5,1)-(6,75): Non-exhaustive patterns in function add
```

... because every Point.fromInteger produces a Point2D, even if we expect a Point3D. I would like to have a way to say in "instance Num Point" that if a Point2D is needed then fromInteger is fromIntegerToPoint2D else fromIntegerToPoint3D. But I don't know how to make a choice based on the return type.

Any hint ? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you need to distinguish `Point2D`and `Point3D` at the type level, so you can give them different `Num` instances.

Comment: Hint? No.  Fact? Yes.  You need different types for the two points if you want fromInteger to automatically translate literals to one of two forms.  Another type has more benefits than this - your abuse of `Point` for both two and three dimensions is really hackish and means that operations like `+` are partial.  For example `Point2D x y + Point3D a b c` will fail with an incomplete pattern match.

Comment: @user2407038 and M. DuBuisson :

Thank you for your answers, this make sense ! I will post the working version soon.

Comment: Can you remove the solution out of your question and submit it as a proper answer? (Slightly related to Meta question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301)

Comment: Yes, thank you for your "meta-feedback".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution :

```
class Point a where
    add :: a -> a -> a
    fromIntegerP :: Integer -> a

data Point2D = Point2D Float Float deriving Show
data Point3D = Point3D Float Float Float deriving Show

instance Point Point2D where
    add (Point2D xa ya) (Point2D xb yb) = Point2D (xa+xb) (ya+yb)
    fromIntegerP v = Point2D (fromIntegral v) 0

instance Point Point3D where    
    add (Point3D xa ya za) (Point3D xb yb zb) = Point3D (xa+xb) (ya+yb) (za+zb)
    fromIntegerP v = Point3D (fromIntegral v) 0 0

instance Num Point2D where
    (+) = add
    fromInteger = fromIntegerP

instance Num Point3D where
    (+) = add
    fromInteger = fromIntegerP

p2D1 = Point2D 1.0 2.0
p2D2 = Point2D 4.0 5.0

p3D1 = Point3D 1.0 2.0 3.0
p3D2 = Point3D 6.0 6.0 6.0

main = do
    putStrLn . show $ sum [p2D1,p2D2]
    putStrLn . show $ sum [p3D1,p3D2]
```

I am still looking for improvements (`instance Num Point2D where` and `instance Num Point3D where`) but it works !

Answer (score 2):

You want to make `Point2D` and `Point3D` be different types, not different constructors for the same type.

Start with this and fill out the definitions:

```
data Point2D = Point2D Float Float
data Point3D = Point3D Float Float Float

instance Num Point2D where
    fromInteger = ...
    (+) = ...

instance Num Point3D where
    fromInteger = ...
    (+) = ...
```